# ValueAnimator makes one element disappear?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to make an animation where I have 4 circles that juggle in different way.

I'm using ValueAnimator to do this, but when I repeat the AnimatorSet a second time, one element disappears and reappears...

What is happening? Someone knows?

here is the code:

```
    objAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    objAnimator.setDuration(DURATION);
    objAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            elements[2].setTranslationX(lateralDistance * value);
        }
    });

    objAnimatorTwo = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    objAnimatorTwo.setDuration(DURATION);
    objAnimatorTwo.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            elements[1].setTranslationX(lateralDistance * value);
        }
    });

    objAnimatorThree = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    objAnimatorThree.setDuration(DURATION * 2);
    objAnimatorThree.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            elements[3].setTranslationX((-lateralDistance * 2) * value);
            elements[3].setTranslationY((float)(-100 * Math.sin(value*Math.PI)));
        }
    });

    animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.play(objAnimator).with(objAnimatorThree)
                .before(objAnimatorTwo);
    animatorSet.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            elements[1].layout(elements[1].getLeft() + (int) lateralDistance,
                    elements[1].getTop(),
                    elements[1].getRight() + (int) lateralDistance,
                    elements[1].getBottom());

            elements[2].layout(elements[2].getLeft() + (int) lateralDistance,
                    elements[2].getTop(),
                    elements[2].getRight() + (int) lateralDistance,
                    elements[2].getBottom());

            elements[3].layout(elements[3].getLeft() + (int)(-lateralDistance * 2),
                    elements[3].getTop(),
                    elements[3].getRight() + (int)(-lateralDistance * 2),
                    elements[3].getBottom());

            presetElementArray();
            animatorSet.start();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
```

here is the method presetElementArray()

```
private void presetElementArray() {
    IndicatorElement temp1 = elements[1];
    IndicatorElement temp2 = elements[2];
    IndicatorElement temp3 = elements[3];

    elements[1] = temp3;
    elements[2] = temp1;
    elements[3] = temp2;
}
```

I'm using an array elements to manage the circles, after one cycle is completed I set the position of each element in a AnimatorListener in the AnimatorSet, after this I swap the elements in the array so, they do different anymations in the second cycle and I repeat.

This is the result:[animation slowed and colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmkBL.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not only change layout, but also reset translations of elements. I mean

```
elements[i].setTranslationX(0)
```

in

```
onAnimationEnd()
```

You didn't ask for this, but I thought it could be helpful...

Some tips to make your code better (smaller):

1. Use `AnimatorListenerAdapter` instead of `Animator.AnimatorListener` if you have empty methods.
2. `ObjectAnimator` is usually faster to code than `ValueAnimator`.

You can find more tips in [Android API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).

I did some refactoring of your code as an example: https://pastebin.com/Fik5F7vQ

Comment: Ok, seem this solved the problem... and I used a couple of your suggestions, thanks.